# Nant how do I list all the targets in the current project?

Tags: nant

I'm constantly trying to remember some of the buried targets in my nant file.
Is there a command that I can run before I run the target that lists the targets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean the command parameter `-projecthelp`, this will show all targets with the descriptions (when specified)
see also the [nant site](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/fundamentals/targets.html)

Comment: exactly, thanks, will award answer soon, wonder if there are any clever tricks anyone else has for the time being.